# Is [java] a good tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed [java](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java) due to a recent suggested edit.  It appears to be used with Minecraft questions to mean "I run a command involving either java.exe or javaw.exe at some point".  Is this useful?

IMO, it doesn't create a useful category.  It's also pretty unintuitive — we don't deal with Java directly here, and there doesn't seem to be any distinguishing between Minecraft options on the command line versus options for the Java environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually as far as filtering and "expertise" is concerned, it's a pretty good tag; one can indeed be an expert on the "client-side" aspect of Java, and be interesting in filtering questions that involve it.

I agree it's counter-intuitive to have something like that on Gaming - I mean, why should we care about the technology behind a game? But it actually makes sense as far as technical support is concerned. In fact, it's quite similar to [source-engine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-engine), which does indeed have some useful questions about the engine itself, e.g.

- [How do you turn on "windowed fullscreen" in TF2 and other Source games?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18029/how-do-you-turn-on-windowed-fullscreen-in-tf2-and-other-source-games)
- [What is the gravity model in Source engine games?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3249/what-is-the-gravity-model-in-source-engine-games)
- [In Source engine games, when are server.cfg and autoexec.cfg executed?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2814/in-source-engine-games-when-are-server-cfg-and-autoexec-cfg-executed)

So I think [java](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java) should stay, and we should create an excerpt for it explaining it should be used for technical-support questions that involve Java-specific stuff.

Comment: Hmm, that does make sense.  I guess it just needs be used better, which a tag excerpt would help with.

Comment: @MatthewRead go steal these 2 rep quickly before someone else comes along and sees this thread, then :)

Comment: Haha, done! Still not used to needing tag-related approvals.