# java tag - merge proposal

Tags: discussion, tag-merging

We have a [java](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java) tag, which was previously used for questions relating to Java issues for a variety of games however it only appears to be used against Minecraft questions and mainly in relation to versions of Java.

For this reason I am proposing a tag merge of Java into Minecraft, with the end result being no more Java tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I oppose this, [for the reasons I've outlined before](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4306/is-java-a-good-tag). Even if it's only used with Minecraft at the moment, it does represent a separate area of expertise.

Comment: Hi Oak, are you suggesting I manually detag the Minecraft questions, leaving Java as a tag with 0 questions on it? If that's the case, the tag will simply get automatically deleted at some point in the future, so we should just take the opportunity to merge instead?

Comment: @pixel I'm not sure how you understood that from my post :) my opinion is that it is a useful tag that should not be removed.